# Custom hostname resolver for JAX-RS client

Tags: java, http, jax-rs, resolve

Is there a way to customize the host name resolution inside a JAX-RS client?

I am using `javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder` to create a client and I would like that for example `https://mytestinghost.tech` resolves `mytestinghost.tech` to an IP I can define; e.g. `1.2.3.4`.

I am either using default connector or [Jetty HTTP(2) connector](https://github.com/nhenneaux/jersey-http2-jetty-connector).

The client is retrieved using the following code.

```
ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
  .trustStore(clientCertificateProvider.getCertificate())
  .withConfig(new ClientConfig().connectorProvider(JettyHttp2Connector::new))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to force the resolution by configuration the underlying `SocketAddressResolver` inside `HttpClient`.

```
ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
  .register(new JacksonJsonProvider())
  .trustStore(HttpUtility.trustStore())
  .withConfig(new ClientConfig().connectorProvider((jaxrsClient, config1) -> {
      final JettyHttp2Connector jettyHttp2Connector = new JettyHttp2Connector(jaxrsClient, config1);
      jettyHttp2Connector.getHttpClient().setSocketAddressResolver((s, i, promise) -> {
          try {
              final List<InetSocketAddress> result = Collections.singletonList(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("1.2.3.4"), managementPort));
              promise.succeeded(result);
          } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
              throw new IllegalStateException(e);
          }

      });
      return jettyHttp2Connector;
  }))
```